# Jni layer in Android

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am confused with Jni layer, NDk LAYER and the C/C++ source code components LAYER  in the Android system.

When writing feature on Android based platform, introducing new custom components:

Can I refer  any component written in c/C++ as  NDK component ?

What is jni, a file which helps loading c/C++ shared objects ?

I have refered below link: It talks about how to use it but not exactly clarifies the naming convention used in Android platform.
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Can someone please clarify the distinction between JNI,NDK and c/c++components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a worlflow.
You have a class named **NativeGoodAlgorithm** written in C/C++.
Write a wrapper for **NativeGoodAlgorithm** called **NativeGoodAlgorithmInterface**(JNI).
Write a Android.mk that links your native code and wrapper to generate a library(.so).
In Android, you load the generated library and write a Java class named **GoodAlgorithm**.
Then you call **GoodAlgorithm** wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Native Interface (JNI) is a way for you to call C++ code from your Java code, and the other way around.

The Native Development Kit (NDK) uses JNI to let you call C++ from an Android application.

You will most likely have to do some work to call existing C/C++ from an Android app using NDK. For example, you'd have to make sure your C/C++ ran on the ARM CPU on the phones you want to support. You'll have to define the data structures you want to pass back and forth between the two layers. I'm not sure what the limitations on OS-level calls are for native code running in an app, but there probably are some.

Comment: if I write my program using  c/c++ language then can I call my component as NDK component ?

Comment: I don't think it will be that simple. You can try, though: take a small part of your C++ and see if you can call it from an Android app using NDK.

Comment: I meant, can I refer/name/adress, my component as NDK if it is written in c/c++ ?  Can I say to everybody that I have written an NDK component ?